# Plotting a swarmplot on a violinplot changes the ylim and truncates the violins

Tags: python, seaborn, yaxis, violin-plot, swarmplot

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np  # for sample data
import pandas as pd

# sample data
np.random.seed(365)
rows = 60
data1 = {'Type 1': ['a'] * rows,
         'Total': np.random.normal(loc=25, scale=3, size=rows)}
data2 = {'Type 1': ['b'] * rows,
         'Total': np.random.normal(loc=60, scale=7, size=rows)}
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d) for d in [data1, data2]], ignore_index=True)

# plot
plt.figure(figsize=(5, 4))
sns.violinplot(x='Type 1', y= 'Total', data=df, inner=None)
sns.swarmplot(x='Type 1', y= 'Total', data=df, color='#000000', size=3)
```

[image]

compared to the plot without `swarmplot`

[image]

Displays out to the image above, how can I change the range displayed?

I've tried [changing `figsize`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D8ON.png). **I didn't have this issue until I overlapped the `swarmplot` onto the `violetplot`.**

#### `df`

```
  Type 1      Total
0      a  25.503763
1      a  26.570516
2      a  27.452127
3      a  30.111537
4      a  18.559157
...
115      b  67.389032
116      b  67.337122
117      b  59.193256
118      b  56.356515
119      b  57.353019
```

Answer (score 3):

- When adding `sns.swarmplot`, or a `sns.stripplot`, to `sns.violinplot`, the limits of the y-axis are changed.

  - This occurs using both the [explicit "Axes" interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-explicit-axes-interface), and [implicit "pyplot" interface](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#the-implicit-pyplot-interface), as shown in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJSwd.png).
  - Using `sns.catplot` with `kind='violin'`, and `.map_dataframe` with `sns.swarmplot` also produces the same issue, as shown in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maDK2.png).
  - This doesn’t occur if plotting `sns.swarmplot` on `sns.boxplot`, as shown in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6c6g.png).
- **Tested in `python 3.11.2`, `matplotlib 3.7.1`, `seaborn 0.12.2`**

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample data
df = sns.load_dataset('geyser')

# plot
sns.violinplot(data=df, x='kind', y='duration', inner=None)
print('ylim with 1 plot', plt.ylim())
sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='kind', y='duration', color='#000000', size=3)
print('ylim with both plots', plt.ylim())
```

```
ylim with 1 plot (1.079871611291212, 5.607761736565478)
ylim with both plots (1.425, 5.2749999999999995)
```

[image]

### Resolution

- Here are three options to resolve the issue:

  1. Capture the `ylim` values after plotting the `sns.violinplot`, and set `ylim` to those values after plotting the `sns.swarmplot`.
  2. Set `ylim` to some specific value after plotting `sns.swarmplot`
  3. Plot `sns.swarmplot` then `sns.violinplot`.
- To have `ylim` start at the "origin", use `y_bot = 0`.
- Using [`matplotlib.pyplot.ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html), [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylim.html), and [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ylim`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ylim.html).

#### 1.

```py
sns.violinplot(data=df, x='kind', y='duration', inner=None)
y_bot, y_top = plt.ylim()
sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='kind', y='duration', color='#000000', size=3)
plt.ylim(y_bot, y_top)
```

[image]

#### 2.

```py
sns.violinplot(data=df, x='kind', y='duration', inner=None)
sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='kind', y='duration', color='#000000', size=3)
plt.ylim(1, 6)
```

[image]

#### 3.

```py
# plot
sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='kind', y='duration', color='#000000', size=3)
print('ylim with 1 plot', plt.ylim())
sns.violinplot(data=df, x='kind', y='duration', inner=None)
print('ylim with both plots', plt.ylim())
```

```
ylim with 1 plot (1.425, 5.2749999999999995)
ylim with both plots (1.079871611291212, 5.607761736565478)
```

[image]

#### Preferentially, use the **explicit** interface

- [Why be explicit?](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/api_interfaces.html#why-be-explicit)

##### `plt.figure` and `.add_subplot`

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 5))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
sns.violinplot(data=df, x='kind', y='duration', inner=None, ax=ax)
y_bot, y_top = ax.get_ylim()
sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='kind', y='duration', color='#000000', size=3, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylim(y_bot, y_top)
```

##### `plt.subplots`

```py
fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
sns.violinplot(data=df, x='kind', y='duration', inner=None, ax=ax)
y_bot, y_top = ax.get_ylim()
sns.swarmplot(data=df, x='kind', y='duration', color='#000000', size=3, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylim(y_bot, y_top)
```

---

#### `df[['duration', 'kind']].head()`

- This real data is similar to the random sample in the OP.

```
   duration   kind
0     3.600   long
1     1.800  short
2     3.333   long
3     2.283  short
4     4.533   long
```