# How to create a violin plot (show-all-points) in the style of Graphpad Prism with seaborn (or other packages)?

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot

I'm trying to get better at plotting from a coding platform and I like using Python and Seaborn.  Graphpad Prism makes some really nice looking plots that show all datapoints which I'd like to emulate.  The example I'm working from is a violin plot with the datapoints overlaid on it.

Example of Prism plot I'd like to emulate:

[image]

When I make a plot like this in Seaborn, I don't like how all the datapoints are within a single vertical line, unlike with Prism how the points are distributed so as to not overlap if possible.

I looked into "jittering" the datapoints, but I don't like how that looked either: datapoints would still often overlap, and it looks very disorganized to jitter the data where it doesn't need to be (such as at the tails of the data where it is more spread out, I like that Prism keeps those points on the center line).

Is there a way to make a plot like this through Python?  I like Seaborn but if this works better through a different package, let me know.  And if R might work better too, I'm open to trying that too.  Thanks in advance!

Example of `Seaborn` violin plot I made:

[image]

Comment: [Plotting a swarmplot on a violinplot changes the ylim and truncates the violins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76317790/plotting-a-swarmplot-on-a-violinplot-changes-the-ylim-and-truncates-the-violins) shows how you could combine a violinplot with a swarmplot.